# c++ save class templated function pointer inside map

Tags: c++

I'm having a small problem which I can't wrap my head around.
I have a function that looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<Environment>& CreateEnvironment(sf::Vector2f& _position, bool _addToStatic = false);
```

This is my function pointer typedef

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<Environment>& (WorldEditor::*CreateEnvironmentPtr)(sf::Vector2f&, bool);
std::map<std::string,CreateEnvironmentPtr> listEnv;
```

And I'm trying to simply do this:

```
listEnv["test"] = &CreateEnvironment<Coin>(sf::Vector2f(200,200), false);
```

And i get the following error:

> `error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty> *' to
>   'std::unique_ptr<_Ty> &(__thiscall WorldEditor::* )(sf::Vector2f
>   &,bool)'`

I understand what the error is saying, but I don't know how to solve it. Also why does it even care about the return type when I'm pointing to the address of the function?

Best regards
nilo

Comment: It looks like your assignment to `listEnv["test"]` is the address of the result of a function call.

Comment: `listEnv["test"] = &CreateEnvironment<Coin>;` assigns a pointer to the function.

Comment: yes exactly. But i simply wants to store the class function pointer, call the function later and get the return value. If i set the return type to void, everything works, but not like this, which looks correct to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how are you calling the function later? (the code)

Comment: I haven't got that far yet. But simply iterate through the map and auto& returnVal = (it.second)(args, args) i guess

Comment: In terms of what you are doing wrong, the code you have written will call the function, and the address of the result will be assigned to `listEnv["test"]`. If you don't want the function to be called, don't use the parentheses operator on the function, as that means "call the function".

Comment: why are you returning a reference to a `unique_ptr`

Comment: well the createenvironment function creates a object and puts it inside a vector which the game iterates through and renders. Returning a reference gives me the option to manipulate the object after creating it, for example I might set it to be controlled by the player etc.

Answer (score 2):

problems such as these are often much better solved with `std::function`

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void()> listEnv;

listEnv.emplace("test", [] {
  CreateEnvironment<Coin>(sf::Vector2f(200,200), false);
});
```

to call:

```
listEnv.at("test")->second();
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your post I am not sure if you are attempting to create the member function pointer and map inside the `CreateEnvironment` class or outside of it, so I'll solve what I think is the more difficult problem of pointer to a separate object's member function.

I simplified your classes like so:

#### Environment

```
struct Environment
{
    int i = 1;
};
```

#### Coin

```
struct Coin
{
    int k = 0;
};
```

#### WorldEditor

```
struct WorldEditor
{
    template <typename T>
    std::unique_ptr<Environment> CreateEnvironment(int& _j, bool _addToStatic = false)
    {
        return std::make_unique<Environment>();
    }
};
```

#### Solution: Map an object's member fn pointer, and then call it later

(I will be using C++11/14 syntax in my answer)

```
//declare a pointer to member function in WorldEditor
using CreateEnvironmentPtr = std::unique_ptr<Environment> (WorldEditor::*)(int&, bool);

//declare an object of type WorldEditor, because member function pointers need a "this" pointer
WorldEditor myWorldEditor;
int myInt = 42;

//map a string to the CreateEnvironment<Coin> function
std::map<std::string, CreateEnvironmentPtr> listEnv;
listEnv["test"] = &WorldEditor::CreateEnvironment<Coin>;

// call the member function pointer using the instance I created, as well as
// the mapped function
(myWorldEditor.*listEnv["test"])(myInt, false);

// (printing member value to cout to show it worked)
std::cout << (myWorldEditor.*listEnv["test"])(myInt, false)->i << std::endl; // prints 1
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/ISsSXY)

---

### Solution 2: use std::bind and std::function

Perhaps we already know the parameters to the member function call at the time we create the entry for map. Using `std::bind` with a `std::function` will help us achieve that (Similar to Richard Hodges' [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30358056/27678)):

```
// now our "function pointer" is really just a std::function that takes no arguments
using CreateEnvironmentPtr = std::function<std::unique_ptr<Environment>(void)>;

//declare an object of type WorldEditor, because member function pointers need a "this" pointer
WorldEditor myWorldEditor;
int myInt = 42;

//map a string to that function pointer
//ensure it gets called with the right args 
// by using std::bind (which will also make the arg list appear the be void at call time)
// note that std::bind needs an instance of the class immediately after
// listing the function it should be binding
// only afterwards will we then pass the int& and bool
std::map<std::string, CreateEnvironmentPtr> listEnv;
listEnv["test"] = std::bind(&WorldEditor::CreateEnvironment<Coin>, &myWorldEditor, myInt, false);

// the mapped function
listEnv["test"]()->i;

// (printing resulting unique_ptr<Environment>'s member to cout to show it worked)
std::cout << listEnv["test"]()->i << std::endl; // prints 1
```

[Live Demo 2](http://ideone.com/6Gm0QY)

Comment: Cheers mate. Good answer as well. Next time ill come across this problem, ill know what to do